# Google Sheets function "=Year(2001)" returns 1905

Tags: date, google-sheets, text

When I enter =Year() with any year as argument (e.g. 2010), I always get 1905 as a result

- At first i thought that my cell reference is broken, but it also happens when I enter the year directly into the formula.
- The same thing happens when I enter =TEXT(2010;"YYYY") --> 1905 ???

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is it correct. The argument is an integer: the number of days after "Google Sheet epoch". So you are getting the year of the 2010th day. In this manner, all date functions can work with the same cell just by looking the numerical value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write

```
=YEAR(DATE(2010,1,1))
```

What 2005 is equivalent to

```
=INT(DATE(1905,3,19))
```

YEAR takes an integer value, DATE will convert for you the year, month and day to an integer.